# Select row between certain range of date

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look which room is available between 2 dateTimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511205/how-to-look-which-room-is-available-between-2-datetimes)

I have this row of data

```
|room_id|checkin     |checkout  |
+       +            +          +
|1      |2012-05-02  |2012-05-09|
```

But I don't want to choose this row which betweeen two dates

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reservations`  `res` 
WHERE (2012-05-03 
   NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date AND res.expected_checkout_date) 
 AND COALESCE(2012-05-08 
   NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date AND res.expected_checkout_date)
```

However, I am still getting this row which is not suppposed to come up. Actually, my idea is to choose all rows which is not between these two date. Any idea?

### Update 1

Basically, someone is trying to reserve a room from 5/3 to 5/8 and I want to see a list of rooms that would meet that criteria.

Comment: is checkin, checkout and the value you're passing in all DATE data types?  or are you doing comparison at a string level?  What is that coalese doing? it's always going to be 2012-05-08, and I'm surprised you're not getting a syntax error as I thought it required at least 2 parameters.

Comment: Yes, it is DATE type and not I am not doing comparision in string level

Comment: Lastly, what are you trying to do here?  What's the functional requirement.  I'm not following the technical example you have.. Are you wanting all rooms which would be vacant for the dates specified?  Basically, someone is trying to reserve a room from 5/3 to 5/8 and you want to see a list of rooms that would meet that criteria?  If so wouldn't you need to join back to rooms since there wouldn't be a reservation in the system?

Comment: Yes, this actually what I want to achieve.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered several times already on SO: leverage the existing knowledge: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615225/hotel-reservation-system-sql-identify-any-room-available-in-date-range or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511205/how-to-look-which-room-is-available-between-2-datetimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what types are `checkin` and `checkout`, whether strings or dates/datetimes, the issue seems to have to do with the fact your date constants are not delimited with single quotes (i.e. they are not represented as strings, as they should have been.)

So, just try the following instead of your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reservations`  `res` 
WHERE ('2012-05-03' 
   NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date AND res.expected_checkout_date) 
 AND COALESCE('2012-05-08' 
   NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date AND res.expected_checkout_date)
```

Comment: Thank you, it was because of this. It works

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservations AS res 
WHERE res.expected_checkout_date <= '2012-05-02'
   OR '2012-05-09' <= res.expected_checkin_date
```

Comment: Their conditions are inclusive and they want the dates to be *outside* the inclusive ranges, i.e. I think your `<=`s should probably be `<`s.

Comment: @Andriy: Yes but you have `[3,8]` range, I have `2` to `9`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you switched the constants, sorry! But why did you do that? They might be script arguments, you know.